# Android network provider and gps provider returning null

Tags: android, gps-time

I have done this code where I want to get longitude and latitude , but using both network provider and gps provider i get my location null . even if  gps is enabled ... why so?

> ```
>       boolean isGPSEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
>       boolean  isNetworkEnabled = lm
>                 .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
>         Location location = null;
>         if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
>         {  
>         }
>         else if(isGPSEnabled ) {
>             location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
>             if(location == null)
>             {                   
>                 if(isNetworkEnabled)
>                     location =                                   lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);                 
>                 if(location == null)
>                 {
>                 }
>             }
>         } else if(isNetworkEnabled){
>             location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);   
>             if(location == null)
>             {
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597076/network-provider-and-gps-provider-returning-null-values?rq=1

Comment: There is something in new version of Android...
are you using device or emulator. if device what is its version.

Answer (score 0):

there are several reason of not getting co ordinates but incase of yours, since your `gps` is enabled (`remember gps takes alot of time to get coordinates`) and you are checking for gps first in your code, it is not go to the `network` part because you are using if else.so change your code to like this and check for network first.

```
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {  
        }
      else if(isNetworkEnabled){
            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);   
            if(location == null)
            {
            }
        }
        else if(isGPSEnabled ) {
            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(location == null)
            {                   
                if(isNetworkEnabled)
                    location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);                 
                if(location == null)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: My error appears to be on sony handsets, is it any different?

On all cases I am geting 0 - 0 ..